# Android Buttons: getting a text back

Tags: java, android, button, gettext

I'll go over this as quick as posible. I'm developing an app that needs a comprobation from the text of a button. Let me explain it in a code-way. If my button has "This text", then do that. I've been trying for the past two days several diferent things, and I'm on a dead end, so I'm asking. Here is my code:

XML:

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/bHiddenL1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_margin="18dp"
                android:text="@string/NotUsed"
                android:maxLength="10" />
```

Java:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.newnotebookbutton);
            initializeNotebookNewSubject();


        }


            public void initializeNotebookNewSubject() {

                NewTextInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewNotebookButtonCreateSubjectButton);
                OKButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOkButton);
                Button1L = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bHiddenL1);           
                Button2L = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bHiddenL2);           
                Button3L = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bHiddenL3);           
                Button4L = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bHiddenL4);           
                Button5L = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bHiddenL5);           
                Button1R = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bHiddenR1);           
                Button2R = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bHiddenR2);           
                Button3R = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bHiddenR3);           
                Button4R = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bHiddenR4);           
                Button5R = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bHiddenR5);           

                OKButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            }


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String b1L = Button1L.getText().toString();
                String b2L = Button2L.getText().toString();
                String b3L = Button3L.getText().toString();
                String b4L = Button4L.getText().toString();
                String b5L = Button5L.getText().toString();
                String b1R = Button1R.getText().toString();
                String b2R = Button2R.getText().toString();
                String b3R = Button3R.getText().toString();
                String b4R = Button4R.getText().toString();
                String b5R = Button5R.getText().toString();

                if(b1L == "Not Used" && NewTextInput.getText().toString() != null){

                    NewSubjectBundle.putString("title1L", NewTextInput.getText().toString());
                    NewSubjectBundle.putInt("int", 1);
                     mIntent.putExtras(NewSubjectBundle);
                     setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);
                     finish();
```

Let me specify better my problem. Whenever I'm trying to do the  "String b1L = Button1L.getText().toString();", I get an error in the logcat saying that the pointer is Null. How should that be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't compare content of Strings using ==.

```
b1L == "Not Used"
```

should be

```
b1L.equals("Not Used")
```

or even better

```
"Not Used".equals(b1L)
```

[How do I compare strings in Java ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Okay, thanks, I didn't know that. Anyways, that's not really my problem. The thing is that whenever I try to do the "String b1L = Button1L.getText().toString();" there is an error in the logcat saying that the content is null. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

ZouZou is right. But in your case, even better is:

```
b1L.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.NotUsed));
```